# Routing issues with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm going off a John Linquist video doing some basic AngularJS routing.  When I don't have my table in a `partials` folder and in my `index.html` page (and not using `ng-view` so I don't have to configure routing, it works fine.  However, I try to inject my a partial view of my table with `<ng-view></ng-view>` then I get the error: http://goo.gl/nZAgrj (from the angular docs)

app.js

```
angular.module('enterprise',[])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when("/",{templateUrl:"/partials/list.html"})
    })
//this is the that iterated over in the partial view's ng-repeat
function AppController($scope){
    $scope.crew =[
        {name:'Picard',description:'captain'},
        {name: 'Riker',description:'number 1'},
        {name:'Word',description:'Security'}
    ]
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular JS Routing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="enterprise" ng-controller="AppController">
    <a href="/"><h2>Enterprise Crew</h2></a>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
     //list.html should be injected here
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

list.html

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="width: 250px">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in crew">
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.description}}</td>
        <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include ng-route.

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).
```

cdn:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.min.js

Comment: Well, thank you sir.  I guess I found a version of angular that didn't have routing built in because in all of the tutorials I've seen they don't include it specifically, but this was it.

Comment: They dont include it in the 1.2 versions.  Its a common issue.

Answer (score 0):

And is it working like that?

```
angular.module('enterprise',[])
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/",{templateUrl:"/partials/list.html"})
})
.controller("AppController", ['$scope',
    function ($scope){
        $scope.crew =[
            {name:'Picard',description:'captain'},
            {name: 'Riker',description:'number 1'},
            {name:'Word',description:'Security'}
        ];
    }
 ]);
```

Ok, response is here : [AngularJS 1.2 $injector:modulerr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr)

Comment: It's working as long as I'm not trying to use routing.

Comment: Nix was right, it was because the routing js file wasn't included as a dependency in the module.