# Why does routing in my app doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, route-provider, angularjs-injector

I use angularJS and want to add routing to my app. But I have error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module countriesModule due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'countriesModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

This is my file app.js:

```
var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', ['ngRoute', 'countriesDataModule']);

countryApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('data/', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/countries.html',
        controller : 'CountriesListCtrl'
    }).when('data/:countryUrl', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/country-details.html',
        controller : 'CountryDetailsCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/countries'
    });
}]);
```

And file controllers.js:

```
var countriesDataModule = angular.module('countriesDataModule', []);

countriesDataModule.controller('CountriesListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/countries.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.countries = data;
        $scope.selectedProp = 'countryId';
    });
}]);

countriesDataModule.controller('CountryDetailsCtrl', ['scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.countyUrl = $routeParams.countryUrl;
}]);
```

Index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="countriesModule">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/common.css">
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-2.2.3.min/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Сountry for travel</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Structure of my project:

[image]

I have visited other pages and seen there some tips:

> [AngularJS 1.2 $injector:modulerr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr)
>
> [Angular JS Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045416/angular-js-uncaught-error-injectormodulerr)
>
> https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=countriesModule&p1=%E2%80%A62Flocalhost:8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:21:19

but unfortunately it didn't help me

Comment: I see only a reference to `countriesDataModule`

Comment: Somewhere you're referencing countriesModule, which isn't shown in your code example

Comment: In error: Module 'countriesModule' is not available! But I use in my application another module countriesDataModule. Why do I have that error?

Comment: please post your index.html

Comment: Look Look above, I have added index.html

Comment: I am sorry, i have noticed where I made mistake. I changed name of module in controllers.js, but I forgot change it in html ng-app directive, but Chris Newman you helped me think about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is no reference to anything called countriesModule in the code you shared.