# Issue with angular-route.min.js | Error Chrome Console [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome, error-handling

!!Total beginner here!!

I have run into an error - chrome console gives me an error regarding:

```
 [$injector:modulerr]
```

The problem is that I have not installed angular-route.min.js which is what you're supposed to do in all angular versions after 1.2. My trouble began when I installed angular-route.min.js, put it in the same file as angular and my HTML files, referenced it in the code with `<script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>` but nothing happened.

**I also put angular.module('app.js', ['ngRoute']); into my js file.**

There are no typos in my code, I checked for those. On top of all that the console gives me an error saying angular-route.min.js was not found.

All help welcome, I have spent a long time googling but nothing came of it.

```
(function () {
'use strict';
    
angular.module('MSgApp', []);
    controller:('MsgController', MsgController);
angular.module('app.js', ['ngRoute']);

MsgController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function MsgController($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Chris";
    $scope.stateOfBeing = "hungry";
    $scope.sayMessage = function () {
        return "chris likes to eat cookies";
    };
    
    $scope.feedChris = function () {
        $scope.stateOfBeing = "fed";
    };
}

})();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='DIApp'>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>custom attributes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="app.js"></div>
    <h1>expressions and interpolation</h1>
    
    <div ng-controller='MsgController'>
        {{name}} has a message for you: <br>
        {{sayMessage()}}
        <div>
            <button ng-click="feedChris()">Feed chris</button>
            <br>
            <img ng-src="D:/stuff/coursera angular/chris_{{stateOfBeing}}.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

[image: errorimg]

### Errors after unminified both angular and angular-route

[image: errorimg2]

[image: errorimg3]

Comment: I have included a screenshot of the console, need anything else just ask, I really wanna resolve this issue.

Comment: @FedericoBaù nope, position doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: I unminified both angular and angular-route, not much happened, I am now down to two errors, I'll edit the pictures into my question. The first error is in a file I do not even know exists and it complains about <!DOCTYPE html>, then there's the one that complains about the dot in front of .controller on the 5th line of my JS code.

Comment: ok, yes update with the 2 new errors you get. But If I understood means that you followed my answer correct? Now that error is different and you get a new one or you get 2 new? Ok i see now the pict, seems are 2 different and new. Maybe is good, going towards a solution

Comment: Ok, but I see that you have Unminified your self? so may be error prone. Did you try to use The CMD version like so: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js"?

Comment: I have come across another code in the Coursera course and this one seems to be working after putting the three links from the answer by @ulmer-morozov into the head tag instead of referencing files on my pc. I guess that's it, I'll just use these links instead from now on, thanks, bro @ Federico Baù.

Comment: That's awesome, I was thinkig to start a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) but hopefully it's solved :) I added your comment in the answer its self so that will help other people in the future ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per StackOverflow --> [Angular JS Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045416/angular-js-uncaught-error-injectormodulerr/31505393#31505393):

---

**EDIT**: This is what ultimately solved the issue and what [Chris B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12038238/chris-b) did to make it work :

> I have come across another code in the Coursera course and this one seems to be working after putting the three links from the answer by @ulmer-morozov into the head tag instead of referencing files on my pc. I guess that's it,

---

From Answer of [@ulmer-morozov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31505393/13903942):

In development environments I recommend you to use **not minified distributives**. And all errors become more informative! Instead of `angular.min.js`, use `angular.js`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.js">     
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.js">
```

---

From Accepted Answer [@Lauri Elias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045485/13903942):

Try adding this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

---

From Answer of [@Khanh TO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045512/13903942):

Try adding:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js">
```

and:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute','ngResource']);
function TwitterCtrl($scope,$resource){
}
```

You should call `angular.module` only once with all dependencies because with your current code, you're creating a new `MyApp` module **overwriting** the previous one.

From [angular documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045416/angular-js-uncaught-error-injectormodulerr/31505393#31505393):

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the
> module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use
> angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.

---