# angular MINERR_ASSET not found 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm getting an error logged to the console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/js/lib/angular/MINERR_ASSET 404 (Not Found)
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr) and it said it was a result of not inculding ngRoute module, but I do!

public/js/app.js:

```
window.app = angular.module('mean-blog-seed', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource',     'ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'mean-blog-seed.controllers', 'mean-blog-seed.services']);
```

Then I have a jade file that references angular-route.js:

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='js/lib/angular/angular.min.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='js/lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='js/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='js/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='js/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js')

script(src='js/app.js')
script(src='js/config.js')
script(src='js/services/global.js')
script(src='js/controllers/posts.js')
script(src='js/controllers/header.js')
script(src='js/filters.js')
script(src='js/directives.js')
```

The repo is [here](https://github.com/jasonshark/mean-blog-seed)

**Update:**
I posted the issue on github and got referenced to this crazy answer: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4675

> The ng-closure-runner runs an angular specific pass during compilation
>   which adds a definition for MINERR_ASSET, that asset is not included
>   with any of the 1.2.x releases (the only releases with source maps).
>   However, the source map references MINERR_ASSET as a source and as a
>   result there is a 404 when requesting the file.
>
> I've only quickly glanced at the grunt tasks and also
>   ng-closure-runner, but I'm under the impression this is likely the
>   ng-closure-runner included minErr.js or some file generated based on
>   it. Either way the correct asset should be packaged with the other
>   source files or MINERR_ASSET should be removed from the source map
>   "sources".

Comment: have you tried to use absolute path instead of relative and remove base(href='/') ?

Comment: As I can see the issue is fixed ?https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/a29bff1c98161495fb304d0195c4d2916b357686

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4675

The above code led me to check out that problem and you are getting a call to ng-closure-runner (here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a29bff1c98161495fb304d0195c4d2916b357686/bower.json).

Try including [minErr.js](https://github.com/angular/ng-closure-runner/blob/master/src/minErr.js) in your JS files.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I noticed that in Safari I was getting the same error.

```
"sources":["angular.js","MINERR_ASSET"]
```

to:

```
"sources":["angular.js"]
```

and added non minified version of angularjs files associated with minified version to fixed the console errors. If you are using production version of angularjs, which should be minified version, make sure you add map associated with the library files or you may have unwanted server errors.

Answer (score 0):

in the .map file, I changed

```
"sources":["angular.js","MINERR_ASSET"],
```

to :

```
 "sources":["angular-sanitize.js"]
```

no longer getting error in console.

Comment: I don't even have a .map file. What's that for?

Comment: It's for debugging. When you use a minified js file, the function and variable names are non-descriptive. The map file gibes you access to the original names.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue once, make sure you have all three files :

```
angular-route.js
angular-route.min.js
angular-route.min.js.map
```

in your library/vendor folder. 
and your app definition contains ngRoute :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
```

Please vote if this resolution helps you. or share your app.js/error if you still have this issue.

Thanks