# Setup error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm getting that `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]` error related to 1.2 and needing [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) installed. I read about that [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=store&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.23%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dstore%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fleongaban%2FProjects%2FAngular%2F_Codeschool%2Fsrc%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js:6:450%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fleongaban%2FProjects%2FAngular%2F_Codeschool%2Fsrc%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js:20:494%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fleongaban%2FProjects%2FAngular%2F_Codeschool%2Fsrc%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js:21:502%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fleongaban%2FProjects%2FAngular%2F_Codeschool%2Fsrc%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js:33:267%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fleongaban%2FProjects%2FAngular%2F_Codeschool%2Fsrc%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js:7:290)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fleongaban%2FProjects%2FAngular%2F_Codeschool%2Fsrc%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js:33:207)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20gc%20(file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fleongaban%2FProjects%2FAngular%2F_Codeschool%2Fsrc%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js:36:309)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fleongaban%2FProjects%2FAngular%2F_Codeschool%2Fsrc%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js:18:170)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fc%20(file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fleongaban%2FProjects%2FAngular%2F_Codeschool%2Fsrc%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js:18:387) and found this [stack answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr).

However I followed all the steps, and am still getting this error.

I downloaded angular-route.min.js and added `angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);` to my app.js file and am still getting the error :(

Not sure what gives, here is my test link: http://bitalicious.co/angular/

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="store">

<div>
    <p>{{"hello" + " you"}}</p>
</div>

<!-- JavaScript
================================================== -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/vendors/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/vendors/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/modules/app.js"></script>
```

And my app.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var app = angular.modules('store', ['']);
    angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
});
```

[image]

---

Ok Update: I am using the [Google hosted AngularJs](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js) instead of the files from AngularJS.org and I also remove document ready, I just have `var app = angular.modules('store', []);` in my app.js file. Now getting different errors:

[image]

Comment: Don't put Angular definitions in a document.ready and don't use jQuery with Angular.

Comment: Hmm, I'll remove the document ready code, but have to use jQuery, vanilla javascript is like Hebrew.... jk

Comment: No it's really not, and Angular makes it very easy to accomplish tasks. Either use Angular or use jQuery, don't use both in the same app.

Comment: No way I can work without jQuery, I removed it and tested... still getting the same bug, so it's not related to jQuery. I use jQuery for effects and Dom manipulation, am expecting to use Angular for dynamic data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok apparently you can't have an angular.module named **'store'** for some strange reason.

Once I changed this:
`var app = angular.modules('store', []);`
`<html ng-app="store">`

To:
`var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);`
`<html ng-app="gemStore">`

Now everytthing works :(

I'll leave this unchecked to give time for someone to leave and answer and comment as to why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by missing inclusion of ngRoute module. Since version 1.1.6 it's a separate part:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>

var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);
```

This is getting reference from: AngularJS 1.2 $injector:modulerr David answer