# angularjs "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]"

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I checked this 
[AngularJS 1.2 $injector:modulerr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr) but it didnot solve my problem

You can find my example here

http://jsbin.com/ziroq/1/edit?html,js,console

```
<html ng-app="app">

<head></head>

<body>
    <h1>example 8</h1> 
    <p>Changing views with routes and $routeProvider</p>
    <p>you need angular-routes.min.js file to use $routeProvider</p>

    <div ng-view></div>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('list', {
                controller: MyController,
                templateUrl: '/example-08-list.html'
            });
 });

  </script>  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possibly `controller: 'MyController',` http://jsbin.com/vatunilumosa/1/edit

Comment: yes that was the problem thanks!