# Difference between angular versions?

Tags: angularjs

I built a simple app with angular 1.0.7 I realized that I was using old version and I wanted to change the version to latest: 1.2 or 1.3 however then my app doesn't work..

How do I know which feature is not supported or what I have to change?

App:

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/ShowOrder/:carId', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/show_order.html',
    controller: 'ShowOrderController'
      }).
      when('/ShowCarOrder', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
    controller: 'showCarsCtrl'
      });
}]);


sampleApp.controller('ShowOrderController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

  $http.get('data.json').
    success(function(data){
      $scope.cars = data;
     $scope.car_id = $routeParams.carId;
    });

});

sampleApp.controller('showCarsCtrl', function($scope, $http ) {

  $http.get('data.json').
    success(function(data){
      $scope.cars = data;

    });

});
```

Live: http://plnkr.co/edit/JpL8gmMJ2hsZistfNoCl?p=preview

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By reading the [official migration guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)

Comment: start by this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router has been moved into its own `ngRoute` route package in Angular 1.2. You need to import that package to make your code work. [See the Plunker here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/pLyRZrEc23UUK4yz2t5K?p=preview)

A note for future debugging: You can diagnose errors like these by following the error messages in the developer console. In this particular case, had you simply clicked the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=sampleApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:unpr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.1%2F$injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.1%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.1%2Fangular.min.js:38:60%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.1%2Fangular.min.js:36:74)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.e%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.1%2Fangular.min.js:36:335)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.1%2Fangular.min.js:35:52)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.1%2Fangular.min.js:35:176%0A%20%20%20%20at%20s%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.1%2Fangular.min.js:7:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.1%2Fangular.min.js:34:456)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Jb%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.1%2Fangular.min.js:38:184) in the error message you would have been redirected to a page that would have told you what to do.

Comment: A lot of useful info thnx! However; I added ngRoute module and route.min.js but still not working..I guess I read more..

Comment: lots of things changed from 1.0.X to 1.2 1.3. Lots of module has been separated from core module. There is no longer any promise autoboxing (  compiler evaluation promises in scope when they resolve ). transclusion changed a LOT. This is no longer possible to have multiple scope ( aka isolated + non-isolated ) scopes on a dom element... and lot more.

Comment: @PierreGayvallet yes, but OP asked about a specific application.

Comment: @PierreGayvallet agreed. And I assume the question will be deleted.