# AngularJs View not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing, ng-view

Hi I am a new comer to angular js. when I load the page it shows two errors

*1 - Error: [$injector:unpr]*

*2 - Error: [$injector:cdep]*

**HTML**

index.html

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <nav>
        <!-- navbar items displaying here -->
    </nav>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
<script src="libs/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="libs/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<!--angular controller file-->
<script src="libs/apps.js"></script>
<script src="libs/controller.js"></script>
<!--Other UI Libraries-->
<script src="libs/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

partials/developers.html

```
  <section class="developer">

  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
<form ng-submit="check()">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus="true"  ng-model-options="{debounce: 300}" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search text here"/>
    </div>
  </div>

</form> 
  </div>
  <div class="sort col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
  <label class="formgroup">Sort By</label>
    <select ng-model="order">
      <option value="name" selected="selected">
        Name
      </option>
      <option value="org">
        Organisation
      </option>
      <option value="designation">
        Designation
      </option>
    </select>
    <label class="formgroup">
      <input ng-model="direction" type="radio" name="order" checked>
      Ascending
    </label>
<label class="formgroup">
        <input ng-model="direction" type="radio" name="order" value="reverse">
        Descending
</label>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="col-md-6 mydiv"  ng-clock>
      <ul ng-show="search  ">
        <li class="items" ng-repeat="item in list | filter:search | orderBy:order:direction" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
            <label class="lbl">Name</label><p class="text name" ng-bind="item.name"></p>
            <label class="lbl">Designation</label><p  class="text desig" ng-bind=" item.designation"></p>
            <label class="lbl">Organisation</label><p  class="text org" ng-bind="item.org"></p>
              <div class="clear"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</div><!--Container fluid closes-->

</section>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module("MyApp",[
    'ngRoute',
    'appController'
    ]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.
    when('/list',{
        templateUrl : 'partials/developers.html',
        controller:'DeveloperController',
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/list'
    });

}]);
```

**controller.js**

```
var appController = angular.module("appController", []);
appController.controller('DeveloperController', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {

   $scope.name="asdsas";

}]);
```

see the console image [here](http://s6.postimg.org/wy9v9z069/Untitled.png)

**EDIT**

[this](http://s6.postimg.org/qi5hxmh0h/Untitled.png) is my directory structure of project. will it make any trouble. I'm not running it on wamp or any other server.

anyone please help me to sort it out

Comment: You have a typo in your index.html, first sentence need to be `<div ng-app="MyApp">` instead of `<div ng-app="MyApp"` and the last sentence also need a closing `>`

Comment: hey i had not noticed @Ricconnect 's comment while posting my answer.

Comment: @Ricconnect hei actually I've given like that for a demo, I'm edited the question same as my code, please have a look

Comment: You are still missing a closing tag for your html tag :) `</html` has to be `</html>`. Besides that, your code looks fine I think.

Comment: that all fine in my editor, but still the same error, I think the error might be related with routeProvider

Comment: @chandings its not empty it contains lot of code line,I am adding it in the qn anyway, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused due to missing inclusion of ngRoute module. It needs to be included separately

Try including the following in your scripts

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr) for more details.

Comment: nope, I have added both angular.js as well as angular-route.min.js

Comment: I've created a plunker with your code which has the stuff working. See  this http://plnkr.co/edit/4pGxWf7aKzZ5PxOxZpuM?p=preview

Comment: oh thats is really cool, and it is working fine in plunker, but then why in not here :D

Comment: are you running from a local server? if not it will not load templates. You need to create a localhost using any technology php, node what ever you are comfortable with n run it from that

Comment: @Neetu error was with my route.min.js , I dont why, I have downloaded it form angular js official website. now its worknig fine bcs I'm using CDN.. Thnks

Answer (score 0):

the code provided for index.html is incorrect.
See if this helps

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</div>
```