# cannot load module in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I have simple problem with angularjs

Services.js

```
'use strict'

var restData = angular.module('ccapp.services', ['ngResource']);

restData.factory('Testcust', function ($resorce) {
    return $resorce('http://localhost:8080/CallCenterRest/webresources/testcust',{},{
       query:{method:'GET', isArray:true} 
    });
});
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('ccapp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ccapp.services']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/viat',
            {
                controller: 'viatctrl',
                templateUrl: 'pages/viat.html'
            })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: 'index.html' });
});
```

problem is

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   ccapp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   ccapp.services due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'ccapp.services' is not available! You either misspelled the module
>   name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you
>   specify the dependencies as the second argument.

somebody can help :)

Comment: 1) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr
2) Do you have many questions ? One question -> one question mark

Comment: Are you including the scripttag with `services.js` **before** the scripttag with `app.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the index.html file to ensure that `Services.js`is included by a script tag like so `<script src="whatever-your-path-is/Services.js"></script>`.

If your project was set up such that a grunt or gulp task compiles all javascript files into one file (e.g., `my-app.js`) to be included in index.html by a script tag, then you need to make sure that this `Service.js` file is on the path to be processed by the grunt or gulp task.