# Unable to load data from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-injector

I'm new to angularJs and I created an application which uses ui-routing in it and first loads the Config file which has a default state which calls the component and this component calls the service which fetches the data from API.I took this structure from a [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/2SSO4Y?p=preview).When I run the page it loads the page -> Config -> Component and then throws below error.When i clicked on the error message it said it was related to now declaring the injector correctly. Find the code and error message below.

Index.html
[image]

Config File(config.js)

```
var myApp = angular.module('EmpList', ['ui.router', 'ui.router.visualizer']);
alert('config');
myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
  // An array of state definitions
  var states = [
    { 
      name: 'hello', 
      url: '',
      // Using component: instead of template:
      component: 'Get',
      resolve: {
        people: function(PeopleService) {
          return PeopleService.getAllPeople();
        }
      }
    }
  ]

  // Loop over the state definitions and register them
  states.forEach(function(state) {
    $stateProvider.state(state);
  });
});
```

Component(people.js)

```
angular.module('EmpList').component('Get', {
  bindings: { people: '<' },

  template: '<h3>Some people:</h3>'
})
```

Service(people.js)

```
angular.module('EmpList').service('PeopleService', function($http) {
  var service = {
    getAllPeople: function() {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:50164/api/Employee/get').then(function(resp) {
            return resp.data;
      });
    }
  }

  return service;
})
```

Error
[image]

Error Details
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the error message when you click into it?

Comment: check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18287586/3094731) answer.

Comment: Your HTML refrences EmpCtrl - have you defined this elsewhere? Can you share the code? The pluncker doesn't have an EmpCtrl - looks like you are missing a controller?

Comment: Attached the project in git https://github.com/sainath034/ui-route-sample

Comment: issue was that the component name in config and component people.js should be lower and that removed the error but service is not being called