# AngularJs: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

I have used angular and angular routing

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

In error this file 
Indexcontroller.js

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope']);

app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/ui-login', {
      templateUrl: 'ui-login.html',
      controller: 'loginController'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/ui-login'
    });
}]);
app.controller('loginController', function($scope) {
  //Controller Here

  $scope.submit = function() {
    console.log("hi i m coming");
  }
  console.log("in controller");
});
```

#### Error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A332)

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOYmE.png)

Comment: add the `ngRoute` to the controller as well. [Possible link solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr)

Comment: @ ZombieChowder tx for response and I have tried this but same error

Comment: @Rushidave `angular.js` and `angular-route.js` files should have matching **versions**. Change `1.2.0rc1` to `1.6.9`

Comment: @AlekseySoloveyI changed the same version but same error BTW thx for the response

Comment: @Rushidave you should be more specific. Your error says `myApp`, whereas your module is named `myapp`. You don't pass a controller function in here: `app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope']);`. And for better error logs you can change `.min.js` to `.js`

Comment: inconsistencies between modules, controllers and `js` includes is the source if your issue. Just double check everything and you should resolve this issue easily.

Comment: I added function in controller and change module name myapp to myApp and also change .min.js to .js  but same error

Comment: @ZombieChowder thx for advising I will check everything and solve an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I   solved the issue

I have to put angular.min.js before angular-route.min.js and than it's solved

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```

order matters here

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```